# Using android-async-http to download a large file in android

Tags: java, android, loopj

I am currently using loopj to download very large files (in the size of Gigabytes).

I want to download the files to the sd card if one exists.

With the standard sample provided https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/sample/FileSample.java the file seems that the download happens on the internal storage and only after it'sc completed is put in the external storage.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

if (movie.getMovieUrl() != null) {
    handle = httpClient.get(context, movie.getMovieUrl(), new RangeFileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(file) {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File file) {
            if (null != listener) {
                listener.onComplete();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(long downloadedBytes, long totalBytes) {
            notification.updateProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {
            DownloadException error = new DownloadException(throwable);
            if (null != error) {
                listener.onError(error);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            if (movie.isDownloadPaused()) {
                notification.pause();
            }
            else {
                notification.remove();

                if (null != listener) {
                    listener.onCancel();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How can I download a file to the external storage directly?

Comment: Please show your download code.

Comment: @greenapps added it, is very similar to the sample code for now.

Comment: I see no code that would download anything. `File file = new File(getSDCardStoragePath());` And you are not using 'file' anywhere. And nobody can see what getSDCardSoragePath() does and returns. And you did not tell either.

Comment: `httpClient.get(context, movie.getMovieUrl(), new RangeFileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(file)` is the code responsible for downloading I've updated the sample to be more clear.

Comment: Ok i oversaw that. Well did i?

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Well that is not a path to an SD card indeed.

Comment: Well it sure looks like it from the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() :